# process HttpService generated Observable in NestJS

Tags: axios, observable, nestjs

in my .service file inside of one function, i have

```
    let response = this.httpService.request(config)

    let result = response.pipe(
      map(r=>r.data)
    );

    return result
```

the server can successfully create a 201 response returning the result. But i want to extract some data from the response and then return result. How can i do that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

1. use `lastValueFrom(observableMethod)` to change the observable into a promise and `await` it as normal
2. use the observable pipeline and operators like `map` and `mergeMap` to process extra data. You can chain as many of these operators as you'd like, and then just return the observable and let Nest handle the subscription to it